# How to run a plugin goal from terminal

Tags: maven, plugins

I have a multi-module project

One module uses a special plugin - maven-glassfish-plugin

I've got a problem with this plugin - it can't create new domain. Goal create-domain failed

I wanna to run this goal from terminal with key -X to view the full log. But I don't know how to do it - previously I used IDE to run goals

How to run chosen plugin goal from terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `mvn glassfish:<goal>`

You can find the available goals and further documentation [here](http://maven-glassfish-plugin.java.net/plugin-info.html)

The maven binary must be accessible with the `PATH` lookup and the `M2_HOME` environment variable should be set to tell maven where to operate. You can find more details on configuring this [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/development/guide-building-m2.html)